Does this mixed-support product have the countable approximation property?
Recall that a forcing order $\mathbb{P}$ has the countable approximation property if for any $\mathbb{P}$-generic filter $G$ and any $x\in V[G]$, if $x\cap y\in V$ for any countable $y\in V$, $x\in V$. In other words, $\mathbb{P}$ adds no fresh sequences.
It is a classical fact that the iteration $\operatorname{Add}(\omega)*\dot{\operatorname{Add}}(\omega_1)$ (and in fact any iteration of an $\omega_1$-square-cc. and a countably closed forcing) has the countable approximation property. Moreover, the same can be shown for any finite product $\prod_{k<n}(\operatorname{Add}(\omega)*\dot{\operatorname{Add}}(\omega_1))$. However, this is not clear when taking infinite products. In this case, to guarantee the preservation of $\omega_1$, we use the mixed support product: Let $\mathbb{P}$ consist of pairs $(p,q)$ of functions on $\omega$ such that for all $n\in\omega$, $(p(n),q(n))\in\operatorname{Add}(\omega)*\dot{\operatorname{Add}}(\omega_1)$ and for cofinitely many $n\in\omega$, $p(n)=\emptyset$. This forcing can be projected onto from the product of an $\omega_1$-Knaster and a countably closed forcing, so it preserves $\omega_1$.
Question: Does $\mathbb{P}$ have the countable approximation property?
Edit: Here is a sketch for why finite products of $\operatorname{Add}(\omega)*\operatorname{Add}(\omega_1)$ have the approximation property. This uses the following Theorem from my paper https://arxiv.org/abs/2401.13446 (which is in its proof heavily based on proofs of Unger and Mitchell):
Theorem: Let $(\mathbb{P}\times\mathbb{Q},R)$ be an iteration-like partial order such that $(\mathbb{P},b(R))$ is square-$\omega_1$-cc. and $(\mathbb{P}\times\mathbb{Q},t(R)))$ is countably closed. Then $(\mathbb{P}\times\mathbb{Q},R)$ has the countable approximation property.
Here we work with partial orders of the form $(\mathbb{P}\times\mathbb{Q},R)$ which are not necessarily product orderings (e.g. iterations $\mathbb{P}*\dot{\mathbb{Q}}$ can be viewed as orderings on the product $\mathbb{P}\times\dot{\mathbb{Q}}^{\mathbb{P}}$, where $\dot{\mathbb{Q}}^{\mathbb{P}}$ is the set of all rank-minimal $\mathbb{P}$-names for elements of $\dot{\mathbb{Q}}$). The necessary definitions are in the same paper. The most important property (and the one which distinguishes the finite case from the infinite case) is the ``mixing property'' (included in being strongly iteration-like) which states that given any $(p,q_0),(p,q_1)R(p,q)$ there are $p_0,p_1$ and $q'$ with $(p_0,q')R(p,q_0)$, $(p_1,q')R(p,q_1)$ and $(p,q')R(p,q)$ (this also occurs in Mitchells paper "On the Hamkins Approximation Property")
We view the finite product as an ordering on $\prod_{k<n}\operatorname{Add}(\omega)\times\prod_{k<n}\dot{\operatorname{Add}(\omega_1)}^{\operatorname{Add}(\omega)}$ by letting $(p',q')R(p,q)$ if and only if $(p'(k),q'(k))\leq(p(k),q(k))$ in $\operatorname{Add}(\omega)*\operatorname{Add}(\omega_1)$ for all $k<n$. Then (in the finite case) the mixing property holds because given such $p,q,q_0,q_1$, we can choose $p_0$ and $p_1$ such that $p_0(k)$ and $p_1(k)$ are incompatible for any $k<n$. Then we let $q'$ be such that $q'(k)$ is forced by $p_0(k)$ to be equal to $q_0(k)$ and by conditions incompatible with $p_0(k)$ to be equal to $q_1(k)$ (so in particular this is forced by $p_1(k)$). Then it is clear that $(p_0,q')R(p,q_0)$, $(p_1,q')R(p,q_1)$ and $(p,q')R(p,q)$ (as $q'(k)$ is forced to equal either $q_0(k)$ or $q_1(k)$, both of those are forced to be below $q(k)$). In the infinite case, this of course fails.

This is basically a restricted version of Mitchell forcing, right?  It's only $\omega$-many terms and the $Add(\omega_1)$ posets are in the forcing language of the adjacent $Add(\omega)$ poset, instead of the product of all of them up to that point, as in Mitchell.

Exactly. Sadly, the usual proofs of the approximation property for variants of mitchell forcing make heavy use of the fact that there is a single Add(omega)-poset that all of the collapses depend on.

If it can be done succinctly, could you explain why the countable approximation property holds for the product of length 2?

@MonroeEskew I have added a sketched proof. Please let me know if more details are necessary or something is unclear. I was trying not to blow the question up too much.

This is a nice question. I think that $\mathbb{P}$ does not have the countable approximation property. Here's a sketch of a proof. I'll try to be pretty concise; let me know if you'd like more details.
Suppose that $G$ is $\mathbb{P}$-generic over $V$. In $V[G]$, for each $n < \omega$, let $g_n : \omega_1 \rightarrow 2$ be the $\mathrm{Add}(\omega_1)$-generic function added by the $n^{\mathrm{th}}$ "column" of $\mathbb{P}$. Now define a function $h : \omega_1 \rightarrow 3$ as follows. For every $\eta < \omega_1$ and $i < 2$, let $h(\eta) = i$ if $g_n(\eta) = i$ for cofinitely many $n < \omega$; otherwise, let $h(\eta) = 2$.
We first claim that $h$ is countably approximated by $V$. To this end, let $\dot{h}$ be a $\mathbb{P}$-name for $h$, fix $x \in ([\omega_1]^\omega)^V$, and fix $(p,q) \in \mathbb{P}$. We will find $(p,q') \leq (p,q)$ and $h_x : x \rightarrow 3$ such that $(p,q') \Vdash \dot{h} \restriction x = h_x$.
By standard arguments, using the countable closure of $\mathrm{Add}(\omega_1)$ and the countability of $x$, we can find $q'$ such that $(p,q') \leq (p,q)$ and, for every $\eta \in x$ and $n < \omega$, one of the following alternatives holds:

there is $i < 2$ such that $(p(n), q'(n)) \Vdash \dot{g}_n(\eta) = i$;
there exist $p_0, p_1 \leq p(n)$ such that, for $i < 2$, we have $(p_i, q'(n)) \Vdash \dot{g}_n(\eta) = i$.

Now define $h_x: x \rightarrow 3$ as follows. Given $\eta \in x$ and $i < 2$, if there are cofinitely many $n < \omega$ such that $(p(n), q'(n)) \Vdash \dot{g}_n(\eta) = i$, then let $h_x(\eta) = i$; otherwise, let $h_x(\eta) = 2$. We now claim that $(p,q') \Vdash \dot{h} \restriction x = h_x$. For $\eta \in x$ such that $h_x(\eta) < 2$, this is clear. If $h_x(\eta) = 2$, it follows from a routine genericity argument using the fact that the first coordinate of $\mathbb{P}$ uses finite supports (I can give more details here if needed).
Thus, $h$ is countably approximated by $V$. However, another routine genericity argument shows that $h$ cannot be in $V$. Therefore, this provides a counterexample to the countable approximation property for $\mathbb{P}$.

I worried as much. Thank you for the nice counterexample!

This is very nice.
